# How to revalidate specific views in Db2

Tags: database, view, db2

I need to revalidate all invalid views in a database.
IBM writes on their website, that you can achieve this with

```
CALL ADMIN_REVALIDATE_DB_OBJECTS ('view',NULL, NULL );
```

but that would revalidate all my views, but I only need to revalidate the invalid ones.
I think you could get invalid views with

```
SELECT VIEWNAME FROM SASCAT.VIEWS WHERE VALID='N'
```

Anyways... I don't know how to solve my problem with this Information, I tried out a few things, but I can't find the answer.

Comment: The Db2-LUW documentation states that this sproc will revalidate *invalid* views (which is what you want). You can restrict by schema-name, or by specific view name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description for [ADMIN_REVALIDATE_DB_OBJECTS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0053626.html) states that only invalid objects are revalidated. It also suggests that all invalid objects can be found in this view:    SYSCAT.INVALIDOBJECTS

Thus, the procedure is the correct one.